How do I manage external payment intent changes during the checkout process?
Recently, I was tasked with designing the Stripe integration and checkout flow for an application that I'm working on. We're doing product/order management internally and this is my first experience with e-commerce, so I'm struggling with some problems that I'm certain have already been solved.
Consider this flow:

User adds an item to their cart
User initiates checkout on desktop
User modifies their cart on mobile (our carts are stored in the DB for cross-platform consistency)
User initiates checkout on mobile
User completes checkout on desktop

Now we've confirmed a payment intent that doesn't match the cart/order summary displayed to the user on the desktop checkout page, because:

Per Stripe's best practices, a payment intent for this cart was created during Step 2, then updated during Step 4
Our checkout UI is custom-built using Stripe's Web Elements, so the client secret from that payment intent is used to render the payment form

I understand that this is a corner case (and perhaps even a malicious one at that), but to me it feels like a flaw in my approach; I don't think the system should ever charge an amount that doesn't match what the user sees onscreen. Am I right to be concerned about this, and are there standard approaches to building this type of checkout?

Stripe has a chapter on what to do in this condition here.
The same way you created the PaymentIntent on the backend, you can update it with the new amount and update the element on the frontend.
Of course, you could also go for an alternative flow where you show the payment Element before you create the Intent, in which case this really shouldn't cause a problem in the first place.

I totally missed the section about fetching updates, so thank you! But even with that ability, I would never know when to do the fetch since the payment intent is being updated from a different device.
As for your second suggestion, I was considering both that and finalizing payments on the server. But then I'm not able to reuse payment intents as suggested by the best practices. Will that cause any problems?

"when to do the fetch since the payment intent is being updated from a different device." -> I figured you would store the PaymentIntent ID in the user cart data once you have it created, though I suppose this is very dependent of your implementation.

"As for your second suggestion (...) But then I'm not able to reuse payment intents" -> it's true, while the alternative flow doesn't require you to update the PaymentIntent (since you don't create it until the end) you could run into the same situation if your customer fails the payment then adds something to their cart before trying again. Ultimately while Stripe recommends creating the PaymentIntent before rendering the element, there are situations where this isn't possible for users, hence the existence of alternative flows like this one.

No, that's exactly right. I would store the payment intent ID on the cart, and that's what I'd use to update the intent amount after steps 3-4 in the original question. What I meant was that back on desktop, I have no way to know that the intent has changed, and so I have no way to know that I need to fetch the updates.

Ah I see. And there isn't a payment_intent.updated event you could leverage for this - which is a shame. I understand what you mean by corner case now - as this implies the customer is actively using both devices, which is a bit niche. I think what most Stripe users might do would be to check the intent after the customer submits it before confirming - to ensure amounts match. If not, you can present that information back to the customer in whichever way you find best.

"check the intent after the customer submits it before confirming - to ensure amounts match." -> If that strategy works for you, you could retrieve the intent from the frontend to ease the load on your backend: https://docs.stripe.com/js/payment_intents/retrieve_payment_intent

Thank you for all of the input! I'll keep this in mind as I continue working on the design
